# Почему @OrderBy генерирует ошибку?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate, spring-jpa

Столкнулся с крайне любопытным феноменом, хочу обратить внимание опытных джавистов. Делаю приложение на Spring Boot, база данных PostgreSQL.

Модель:

Абстрактный класс **AbstractNamedEntity**:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public abstract class AbstractNamedEntity extends AbstractBaseEntity {

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 2, max = 100)
    @Column(name = "name")
    protected String name;
}
```

от него наследуется **Theme**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "themes")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Theme extends AbstractNamedEntity {

    // некоторые поля
}
```

который в свою очередь является полем в классе **Program**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "programs")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
@ToString
public class Program extends AbstractBaseEntity {

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
    private StudentDetails student;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "theme_id")
    private Theme theme;

    // другие поля

}
```

и последний класс **StudentDetails**, связанный с Program отношением OneToMany:

```
@NamedEntityGraph(
        name = "student-graph-available-tests",
        attributeNodes = {
                @NamedAttributeNode(value = "programs", subgraph = "programs-subgraph"),
                @NamedAttributeNode("availableThemesForTests")
        },
        subgraphs = {
                @NamedSubgraph(
                        name = "programs-subgraph",
                        attributeNodes = {
                                @NamedAttributeNode(value = "open", subgraph = "open-subgraph")
                        }),
                @NamedSubgraph(
                        name = "open-subgraph",
                        attributeNodes = {
                                @NamedAttributeNode("paragraph")
                        })
        })
@Entity
@Table(name = "student_details")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class StudentDetails extends RegionNamedUserDetails {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    @OrderBy("theme.name")
    private Set<Program> programs;

    // другие поля

}
```

Насколько можно видеть, при вытаскивании StudentDetails я использую NamedEntityGraph, который генерирует вот такой запрос *(вся суть в предпоследней строчке)*:

```
select
    studentdet0_.id as id1_11_0_,
    programs1_.id as id1_6_1_,
    open2_.id as id1_4_2_,
    paragraph3_.id as id1_5_3_,
    theme5_.id as id1_17_4_,
    studentdet0_.user_id as user_id8_11_0_,
    studentdet0_.name as name2_11_0_,
    studentdet0_.patronymic as patronym3_11_0_,
    studentdet0_.surname as surname4_11_0_,
    studentdet0_.region_id as region_i9_11_0_,
    studentdet0_.graduation as graduati5_11_0_,
    studentdet0_.is_distance_learning_allowed as is_dista6_11_0_,
    studentdet0_.tel_num as tel_num7_11_0_,
    programs1_.is_active as is_activ2_6_1_,
    programs1_.student_id as student_4_6_1_,
    programs1_.target as target3_6_1_,
    programs1_.theme_id as theme_id5_6_1_,
    programs1_.tutor_id as tutor_id6_6_1_,
    programs1_.student_id as student_4_6_0__,
    programs1_.id as id1_6_0__,
    open2_.paragraph_id as paragrap3_4_2_,
    open2_.program_id as program_4_4_2_,
    open2_.sort_num as sort_num2_4_2_,
    open2_.program_id as program_4_4_1__,
    open2_.id as id1_4_1__,
    paragraph3_.name as name2_5_3_,
    paragraph3_.graduation as graduati3_5_3_,
    paragraph3_.num_of_tests_for_themes_tests as num_of_t4_5_3_,
    paragraph3_.theme_id as theme_id5_5_3_,
    theme5_.name as name2_17_4_,
    theme5_.min_graduation as min_grad3_17_4_,
    availablet4_.student_details_id as student_1_12_2__,
    availablet4_.theme_id as theme_id2_12_2__
from
    student_details studentdet0_
        left outer join
    programs programs1_
    on studentdet0_.id=programs1_.student_id
        left outer join
    open_paragraphs open2_
    on programs1_.id=open2_.program_id
        left outer join
    paragraphs paragraph3_
    on open2_.paragraph_id=paragraph3_.id
        left outer join
    students_available_themes_for_tests availablet4_
    on studentdet0_.id=availablet4_.student_details_id
        left outer join
    themes theme5_
    on availablet4_.theme_id=theme5_.id
where
    studentdet0_.id=?
order by
    programs1_.theme.name,
    open2_.sort_num
```

Видите, в StudentDetails я отметил поле `programs` аннотацией `@OrderBy("theme.name")`, чтобы программы сортировались, эта сортировка видна в предпоследней строке запроса.

Этот запрос генерировал следующую ошибку: `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: таблица "theme" отсутствует в предложении FROM`. При том, что таблицы theme у меня нигде нет, есть только themes. В итоге я догадался убрать аннотацию `@OrderBy("theme.name")` и ошибка исчезла, запрос стал работать.

Вопрос: а что мне с этим делать? Мне нужна эта сортировка. Почему из-за неё возникает ошибка и как её решить?

Comment: Вы используете не просто имя поля, а с алиасом таблицы: `@OrderBy("theme.name")`. Код полагает, что ему дали имя поля, причём из таблицы `programs AS programs1_` (вот тут и нужно смотреть, почему так получается, и как это поменять). В итоге в SQL это получается `order by programs1_.theme.name,`, и сервер совершенно законно полагает, что `programs1_` - это имя базы данных, а `theme` - это имя таблицы в ней. Как итог - ошибка, ибо такой БД/таблицы просто не имеется.

Comment: Мб дело в `@Table(name = "themes")` и `@OrderBy("theme.name")`, т.е. букавка `s` пропущена в запросе сортировки

Comment: @lampa так нет, мы же в OrderBy указываем не в формате SQL, а в формате типа JPQL. То есть поля указываем так, как они в java-классах расположены. Ну и IDEA всё распознаёт и не ругается.

Comment: @Akina странно, вообще эта аннотация вроде бы не предполагает такого поведения... Почему вы говорите, что programs1_ - это название базы? Разве это как раз не название таблицы/поля? В запросе это так выглядит.

Comment: Именование может быть либо `поле`,  либо `таблица.поле`,  либо `схема.таблица.поле`. В сгенерированном SQL-коде три компонента, т.е. используется последний вариант. *Разве это как раз не название таблицы/поля?* Я не говорю, что это за объект у Вас, я говорю, как оно интерпретируется сервером.

Comment: @Akina я понял, спасибо. Плюс конкретно в моём случае в бд была ещё функция с именем theme, и, возможно, маппинг происходил на неё)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### В @OrderBy нельзя использовать вложенные свойства

---

Ошибка возникала из-за того что я использовал в аннотации @OrderBy в классе StudentDetails вложенное свойство: `"theme.name"`. Так делать нельзя, это приведёт к ошибке. Изменить такое поведение невозможно, поэтому сортировку необходимо либо реализовать другим способом, либо не делать её по вложенному свойству вообще.